# How to Sync data from different Google Sheets to a Google master Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have Team of 15 people updating there data of call backs and other info in the Microsoft Excel 
Now i want to use Google Sheets for Real time data. So i want all of them to use a Google Sheet and a Team leader should have the updates when ever they are updating the there own sheets. Everyone should have there own passwords to open there but an Admin should have access to all of there data in those sheets. I hope you understood my needs. I know its possible with Google Sheets but i don,t know how to prepare one as am new to this platform.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
=importrange("sheet url", "range you want to import")
```

on a separate sheet, it will update dynamically as they change things - I have done this specifically with remote employees previously